# Django - Insert Without Returning the Id of the Saved Object

Tags: django, save, django-mssql

Each time the `save()` method is called on a Django object, Django executes two queries one `INSERT` and one `SELECT`. In my case this is usefull except for some specific places where each query is expensive. Any ideas on how to sometimes state that no object needs to be returned - no `SELECT` needed.

Also I'm using **django-mssql** to connect to, this problem doesn't seem to exist on MySQL.

**EDIT :** A better explanation

```
h = Human()
h.name='John Foo'
print h.id # Returns None, No insert has been done therefore no id is available
h.save()
print h.id # Returns the ID, an insert has taken place and also a select statement to return the id
```

Sometimes I don't the need the retruning ID, just insert

Comment: Well, that's strange, MSSQL supports [`INSERT...OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) so I don't see why it would issue two queries, but then again I am not that familiar with `django-mssql`. Perhaps you could build your own INSERT statements for expensive queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*40ins*'s answer was right, but probably it might have higher costs...

When django execustes a **save()**, it needed to be sure if the object is a new one or an existing one. So it hits the database to check if related objext exists. If yes, it executes an **UPDATE**, orherwise it executes an **ISERT**

Check [documentatin from here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert)...

You can use **force_insert** or **force_update** ,but that might be cause serious data integrity problems, like creating a duplicate entry instead of updating the existing one...

So, if you wish to use **force** , you must be sure whether it will be an INSERT or an UPDATE...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `save()` method with `force_insert` or `force_update` attributes. With this attributes django knows about record existence and don't make additional query.

Comment: The problem's not whether django checks for exsistance or not, it's the fact that after every `INSERT` it runs a `SELECT` statement just to keep the objects `id` handy.

Answer (score 0):

The additional select is the django-mssql backend getting the identity value from the table to determine the ID that was just inserted. If this select is slow, then something is wrong with your SQL server/configuration because it is only doing `SELECT CAST(IDENT_CURRENT(*table_name*) as bigint)` call.